# ArgoCD use sha short as docker tag

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

In my project, the docker images are getting tagged with git commit short sha. When the deployment gets triggered via argocd, how can I instruct it to take the latest commit and use it as an image tag while deployment?